# Настройка категорий (URL) Drupal 7

Tags: php, url, drupal, view

Хочу сделать простенький сайт. Но Друпал мне мешает))).

Есть несколько категорий, у каждой из которых есть подкатегории. В них я хочу публиковать статьи.

Настроил меню через таксономию. (модуль *Taxonomy menu*). Все почти хорошо, но когда переходишь по ссылке в категорию (**НЕ** подкатегорию), то публикации из подкатегорий не показываются.

И тут я решил - нужен модуль *Views*. Но не могу его настроить...

Мне нужен юрл:

```
site.com/category1/
```

для категории и

```
site.com/category1/subcategory1/
```

для подкатегории.

А вьюха заставляет меня сделать страницу... и юрл тогда стает:

`site.com/`**categories**`/category1/`

---

Тогда решил, что с адресом разберусь потом, для начала сделаю выборку во вьюхе... Долго игрался с ее настройкой, и смог сделать выборку только по *ID* таксономии.

`site.com/categories/`**1**`/`

Смог сделать выборку уже не по *ID* таксономии, а по названию.

`site.com/categories/`**Строительство**`/`

Но нужно мне использовать не название, а транслит... который указан в url таксономии, или *машинное имя*

---

**Вопрос**

Как сделать категории от машинного имени (url) ?

Можно сделать категории без страницы категории (`/categories/%`)?
*На каждую страницу делать вюхи не вариант.*

Почему в Drupal нет такой простой функциональности?
Перейти с друпала не могу. Попросили сделать иммено на нем!

ПС: Друпал 7, чистый.

Answer (score 3):

1. Поставить модуль pathauto и там настроить генерируемые пути через токены. Но у термина таксономии нет машинного имени, оно есть только у словаря. Для транслитерации имени поставить модуль transliterate.
2. Да, в настройках views ввести необходимый Путь, например /% Возможно стоит поставить какую-нибудь сборку и посмотреть как там сделано. Или запустить её на том же http://simplytest.me, если у себя нет возможности.
3. Всё есть, надо только искать. Например, пояндексить-погуглить.